# Wrap image inside div with other divs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, photo

There is an Image coming from server:

```
<div class="storyDetail">
 <img src="img/photo.jpg" height="180" width="300" style="float:left;">
</div>
```

Now I want to change this image like this through javascript when page loads:

```
<div class="storyDetail">
 <div class="insta-gallery">
  <a href="img/photo.jpg" class="tt-lightbox">
    <img src="img/photo.jpg" height="180" width="300" style="float:left;"/>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried through Javascript but got nothing because I am not fimilier with Javascript!

Comment: I just remove everything :( as I had faded up to do this!

Comment: Did you make the mistake which you corrected just now (height) only in this post? I'd say you copied the code and the mistake also exists in there.

Comment: No i didn't copied above code! That was mistake only in this post...

Comment: Very easy&&fast with jQuery, if you can use it: https://jsfiddle.net/k1he4fo3/

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer with the help of MR.@sinisake.

```
<!-- Getting Image 'Src' -->
var storyDetailImageSrc= $('.storyDetail').find('img').attr('src');

<!-- Wrapping image with required div(s) --> 
$('.storyDetail img').wrap('<a href="'+storyDetailImageSrc+'" class="tt-lightbox">');
$('.tt-lightbox').wrap('<div class="insta-gallery">');
```

Answer (score 0):

To change text:

1. Add an id to your div:

`<div class="storyDetail" id="storyDetail01">`

2. Define a function:

   ```
   function changeText {
   document.getElementById("storyDetail01").innerHTML = 
   ' <div class="insta-gallery">
     <a href="img/photo.jpg" class="tt-lightbox">
       <img src="img/photo.jpg" height="180" width="300" style="float:left;"/>
     </a>
    </div>';
   return false;  }
   ```
3. Place that function wherever you execute Javascript when loading your page.

If not sure about what you do to that purpose, but the easiest -and dirtiest-, is to add a scirpt at the bottom of the html

```
    <body> -> that's your html page body
--- code code...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        changeText();
    </script>
</body>
```